# Why does LoopBack minify content of JSON configuration files?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am building API server using LoopBack 3. It is frustrating to see how it minifies JSON configuration files like `package.json` and other. Why does it do that and how can I disable this behaviour ?

Comment: double check whether your code editor has any extensions that minify it... loopback doesn't modify source codes...

Comment: No, I work in same code editor in different backend code bases and it does not minify JSON files.

Comment: It's really strange. maybe try to edit that in some notepad app and save and then run? Is it a project that you build by you or it comes from someone else? Perhaps it contains some additional commands in package.json scripts? As Varun said, loopback does not do that by itself.

Comment: Codebase was generated with LoopBack application generator. No specific configuration was added to the codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not intentional, we have fixed the problem in `loopback-workspace` version 4.5.2 (see https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-workspace/pull/546).

Please update your `loopback-cli` install and its dependencies to the latest version, that should fix the problem.

For example:

```
npm uninstall -g loopback-cli
npm install -g loopback-cli
```